# jquery click event on script generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

I have this script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.block-link').click(function() {
          $('body').addClass("gallery-on");
       });

       $('body').delegate('.ps-toolbar-close', 'click', function() {
          $('body').removeClass("gallery-on");
          });
       });
</script>
```

The script is supposed to add the class `.gallery-on` to the `body` when i click on any `.block-link`.
The `.ps-toolbar-close` element is generated through a [**plugin**](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe) (pretty good btw!) that create a modal lightbox when any `.block-link` is clicked.

The first part of the script is working, the second is supposed to remove the `.gallery-on` class from the body, but it just close the lightbox and let the body class where it is.

What am i doing wrong? i'm a beginner with javascript and jquery unfortunately..

My best guess is that since `.ps-toolbar-close` is not yet present in the document when the page loads, no click handler is placed for the second part of the script, though i thought that `.delegate()` was able to handle not yet existing elements, am i wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your first event binding needs to use .delegate in the same way that the second one does if you intend for it to target future elements.

Comment: The first `click` function is just supposed to add the `.gallery-on` class whenever a `.block-link` element is clicked. Those element are already present in the document.

Comment: Did you check if the click event is working in the first place by placing an alert or debugging

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to an interesting property of the delegate method. From the jQuery documentation:

> Additional Notes:
>
> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate
>   to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on
>   any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed
>   by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers,
>   therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by
>   calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

The close method for the modal dialog is being attached lower down in the DOM and is being called prior to your body handler and preventing your handler firing correctly.

Try binding to the [close event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) for the dialog and removing the class there.

Comment: Your suggestion confirm what i was afraid off, the plugin is a third party plugin, and i'm really a novice in this, i really don't know where to put my hands doing this.
The plugin generate a whole structure for the lightbox, in this it generates `.ps-toolbar-close` which is the element-button that close the modal lightbox. The plugin also remove the entire structure when the modal is closed. Ain't there any other way to get around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the 'live' method?
$('.ps-toolbar-close').live('click', function() {
    $('body').removeClass("gallery-on");
});

Comment: hey it's working! may i ask why? i am a very beginner in this, googlin around for not existing dom elements i saw posts suggesting to use `delegate()` instead of `live()`.
Place you answer, so i can accept it! ;)